# How to Get google api key from environment file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to get my google api key from my environment variable using this option below

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=env('GOOGLE_API_KEY')&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it is now working, what might the problem be?

i get error This page can't load Google Maps correctly.

Comment: it should be ``{{ env('GOOGLE_API_KEY') }}`` in your blade file so that blade engine can render.

Comment: 1. you need to echo the key using `{{ config('google_api_key') }}`. 2 You can't use a .env constant directly in a view.  add it to a config file and read the with `config()` .

Comment: @GertB., it can be used though it's not recommended. Because it can cause issues in production because of caching.

Comment: i used {{ env('GOOGLE_API_KEY') }}, same error

Comment: @OMiShah Should not, and in recent versions you can't use it in views.

Comment: i used ur option and its not working, by adding to the config file config/app.php

Comment: <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={{config('google_api_key')}}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @IbegbunemAniemekeLawson did you clear the config cache? `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: add this inside my config/app.php 'google_api_key' => env('GOOGLE_API_KEY', ''),

Comment: yes i cleared php artisan config:clear

Comment: @GertB. it still works as on Laravel v9.34.0.

Comment: You need to specify the config file when calling `config()`. So if it's in your app.php, then it's `config('app.google_api_key')`

Comment: @OMi Shah , yes it is working , but the best practice is to not use env directly in the logic of the program
it is better to transfer it to config file

Comment: @OskarMikael indeed, my mistake

Comment: great..that was the problem..works now..thank u

Comment: @Atabarzegar, yeah that's what I said, it's not recommended. :)

Comment: @OMiShah try in production mode ;-)

Comment: @OMI Shah , yes :)) you exactly say opposite of my  sayings .

Comment: @GertB., may be you try for yourself and check bro :)

Comment: @Atabarzegar, you didn't understand I guess ! I said ``it's not recommended to use env variable directly``. ;)

Answer (score 1):

By placing the key inside config/app.php

```
'google_api_key' => env('GOOGLE_API_KEY', ''),
```

and adding it to my view like this

```
{{config('app.google_api_key')}}
```